# Javascript counter controlled loop using (while) error

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie for java script programming. I want to print integers from 0 to 100. here is my code.

```
    var outputAreaRef = document.getElementById("outputArea");


var i = 0; //Initialize counter
var number = 0;
while ( i <= 100) // Test Counter
    {
      number = number + 1 + "<br />";
        i = i + 1; // Increment counter
        outputAreaRef.innerHTML = number;

    }
```

it prints digit 1 hundred times. but if i change the code like this,
number = number + i + ";
it will print from o to hundred. waht is the difference between the two codes?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing strings with numbers. You need to do numerical computation in one variable and string concatenation in another. To increment number you can re-use `i` variable:

```
var outputAreaRef = document.getElementById('outputArea');
var i = 0;
var number = '';
while (i <= 100) {
    i = i + 1; // numeric addition
    number = number + i + '<br />'; // string concatenation
}
outputAreaRef.innerHTML = number; // it is ok to set html content only once
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work because your output is `number`, and `number` is never changed and will remain as `0` because in the while loop, only `i` is changed.

Also change :

```
outputAreaRef.innerHTML = number;
```

to

```
outputAreaRef.innerHTML = outputAreaRef.innerHTML + number;
```

so that the whole innerhtml of the output area will not be replaced every loop.

---

Modify your while loop and it will work perfectly:

```
while ( i <= 100) {
    number = i + 1 + "<br />";
    i = i + 1; // Increment counter
    outputAreaRef.innerHTML = outputAreaRef.innerHTML + number;
}
```

---

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4st3r3g/)

Answer (score 0):

var `number` became a `String` after first run and digit 1 concat to `number` afterward.